# Is there a Latin equivalent of "lady"?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

In English the word "lady" generally carries a positive connotation - that's why Aung San Suu Kyi is also referred to as "The Lady".

I'm wondering if Latin has an equivalent for "lady". Google Translate gives several options, but none of them seem to carry the same mark of respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try "domina" (feminine noun, which is not necessarily obvious, in Latin) = mistress of a family; lady; wife; lady-love (Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict.).

(Strictly speaking, we are not to discuss (contemporary) political figures; especially ones who generate such bitter controversy--as that one does.)